# Synchronous alternative to PipedInput/PipedOutput Stream API?

Tags: java, servlet-filters

We have a `ServletFilter` that retrieves the `<title/>` from the `ServletResponse`. We do this by leveraging the `Piped*Stream` API in our own extension of `HttpServletResponseWrapper`.

To be more specific, the current approach is as follows (in pseudo-code):

1. Create a pair of `PipedInput` and `PipedOutput` streams, and connect them to each other.
2. Inject the `PipedOutputStream` in our extension of `HttpServletResponseWrapper`.
3. Start a thread that waits for bytes to be written to the `PipedOutputStream` (when it's ready, the thread will read the `<title/>` off of the connected `PipedInputStream`).
4. Pass our extension of `HttpServletResponseWrapper` to `filterChain.doFilter()` (this allows the `Servlet` to process the request and write to the `PipedOutputStream`.

And this is the actual code:

```
        PipedInputStream pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream( BUFFER_SIZE );
        PipedOutputStream pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream( pipedInputStream );

        // ResponseSplitter extends HttpServletResponseWrapper.
        // When getOutputStream() is called, the splitter returns a class called
        // SplitStream, which extends ServletOutputStream, overriding the write() method by
        // writing to both the response's original outputStream and the pipedOutputStream.
        HttpServletResponseSplitter httpServletResponseSplitter =
                new HttpServletResponseSplitter(
                    httpServletResponse,
                    pipedOutputStream,
                    true );

        Future<?> future = null;
        try {
            // Fire off a thread that waits for the PipedInputStream to have 
            // content, then reads data.
            // Specifically, we pass the PipedInputStream to jericho
            // StreamedSource to examine the DOM segment-by-segment, without 
            // buffering the whole document into memory.
            future = recordHistory( httpServletResponseSplitter );

            // On the main thread, we pass the request and responseSplitter
            // down the chain so that the servlet can write to the
            // responseSplitter's splitStream
            chain.doFilter( httpServletRequest, httpServletResponseSplitter );

            // block until the servlet's done writing
            future.get();
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
```

We're trying to avoid the complexity of threads, while at the same time be able to read the `response` document as a *stream*, and thereby retrieve the `<title/>` tag without buffering the *entire* document into memory.

Is there simpler, *synchronous* approach to what we're attempting to do?

edit: added actual code

Comment: You could do this with a decorator `OutputStream` that examines the bytes written to it. It would be helpful if you can show your current filter.

Comment: Also: is your servlet output well-formed XHTML?

Comment: We want to leverage [StreamedSource](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/StreamedSource.html) for inspecting the DOM because it takes care of all the hard stuff for us. Parsing the dom _per byte_ as opposed to _per segment_ isn't ideal..

As for the XHTML, I'm not sure if we can assume it's well-formed. We don't control the response content (server-side is a third-party solution).

Comment: In that case, I think you're stuck with having a second thread. The problem is that the `StreamedSource` is going to block waiting for input if a token crosses a write boundary (ie, one call to `write()` finishes with the bytes corresponding to `<foo`, but the tokenizer needs to read subsequent bytes to determine if that's the entire token).

Comment: That may have been the case. We moved away from leveraging `StreamedSource` and just wrote a state machine instead, processing the response _per byte_ until we got to a state where we've found the title. Each time we find a character while in a `READING_TITLE` state, we would fire a callback that adds the character to a `StringBuilder` in the `ServletFilter`'s `doFilter()` method, until we _exit_ the `READING_TITLE` state. Once the call to `doChain()` comes back to the filter, we proceed and use the `StringBuilder` as we may please, now populated with the title.